# How do I query/parse BMC AR System tickets?

Tags: c#, remedy

Unfortunately I don't have a developer licence to join the BMC Supporter Community to get this information.

All over the net I found how to create a BMC AR System ticket but not how to query for them, or how to parse them. For example I'd like to add the data from them into ListView or similar.

So does anyone know how to query/parse BMC AR System tickets in C#, or perhaps knows of any APIs or libraries that will let me interface to them?

Comment: Does their license allow it?

Comment: And have you checked : https://communities.bmc.com/communities/thread/69327

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sure. about 1000 People in our company work with it. We have several Server/Client official licences.

Comment: the link above didn't help. Maybe you can give me an example how to query 'myLabelname' from 'myFormname'. And put it into a listview. Thank you!

Comment: No idea I'm afraid - I've never used it. How much is a dev license? How much do you measure your time at? If the work is important to your company then maybe they need to do a cost benefit analysis?

Answer (score 2):

Query AR System Remedy ARAPI764.NET C#

Here is a example on how to query a form and return values of specified fields

```
BMC.ARSystem.Server arserver = new BMC.ARSystem.Server();
arserver.Login("servername", "username", "password", "");

//Search a Remedy Form Start

string RequestID = "000000000000001";

string FromForm = ((BMC.ARSystem.EntryDescription)arserver.GetListEntry("someREMEDYform", string.Format("'1' = \"{0}\"", RequestID))[0]).Description;

string qualification = string.Format("'1' = "+ RequestID );

BMC.ARSystem.EntryListFieldList fieldList = new BMC.ARSystem.EntryListFieldList();
fieldList.Add(new BMC.ARSystem.EntryListField(8));
fieldList.Add(new BMC.ARSystem.EntryListField(3));

var entryList = arserver.GetListEntryWithFields("someREMEDYform", qualification, fieldList, 0, 0);

Console.WriteLine(entryList[0].FieldValues[8]);
Console.WriteLine(entryList[0].FieldValues[3]);

Console.ReadLine();

//Search a Remedy Form End
```

Comment: Where would I find servername from your example?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the C-API guide for the functions ARGetList and ARGetEntry.  ARGetList takes a qualification as it's input and returns an array EntryIDs that matched the qualification for the form you select.

ARGetEntry takes an EntryID and an array of ARFieldIDs.  It returns the data for contained in the list of fields (specified by ARFieldIDs) for the records specified by the array of EntryIDs.

Mike